# MatDialogRef .afterClosed Observable

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5, angular-material-6

I am using `MatDialogRef` in order to invoke a Modal from a component.
When closing the `ModalComponent`, I try to get back data, **but** *nothing seems to pass back*.

```
dialogRef = dialog.open(ModalComponent,ConfigObj).afterClosed
  .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

All other features of the Modal including passing data from the `baseComponent` to the `ModalComponent` seem to be working fine.

Comment: I tried to remove all parts of your question that seem unnecessary and distracting. This includes "Angular4/5/6" from the title, which I removed because you can easily use tags to specify versions, so I added the appropriate tags. I also removed your thanks from the end of your question because they were poorly formatted and I did not want to change that up. Apart from that I used backticks ` to highlight code in your question and highlighted your problem with italic and bold text styles.

Answer (score 6):

Old question, but in case anyone else stumbles across this:

DialogRef will return the data you pass in when you call dialogRef.close(). When you're done in your Dialog Component, call:

```
const myDataObject = {
field1: 'My field'
}
dialogRef.close(myDataObject);
```

Then in your parent component, subscribe to the data with:

```
dialogRef.afterClosed()
.subscribe( data => console.log(myDataObject.field1));
```

This will log 'My field'.

The return value of the modal isn't the 'data' object you pass in, it's just whatever you want to return.

Answer (score 4):

First, get the dialog reference:

```
let dialogRef = dialog.open(ModalComponent,ConfigObj);
```

Then, set a subscriber in the same code block:

```
dialogRef.afterClosed()
    .subscribe( data=>console.log(data));
```

Also, remember afterClosed should be invoked `()`, unlike what you did.

Comment: I still cannot get any responce.

Comment: my code : in base component :    
     let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EditComponent, dialogConfig);
     
      
     dialogRef.afterClosed()
    .subscribe( data=>alert("good to be back")); in dialog component : save(){
     this.dialogRef.close(this.passBack);
  }   the alert method never gets called. as if there was never a subscription to the obserrvable

Comment: edit your post and add a working sample in stackblitz.com

Comment: This doesn't specify the origin of the 'data' in the subscription.